# Java script: obter o elemento por ID diz que é NULL

Tags: javascript, html, null

Estou aprendendo a programar em javascript e fiz um pequeno código para fazer a soma de dois números. Eu coloquei para que o resultado fosse sobreescrito em cima de "resultado", mas isso não é feito. Ao usar o inspecionar elemento do chorme ele diz que 'out1' não pode receber null.

```
<script>
    var n1 = window.document.getElementById(n1);
    var n2 = window.document.getElementById(n2);
    var n11 = Number.parseFloat(n1);
    var n22 = Number.parseFloat(n2);
    function somar() {
        var result = n11 + n22;
        var out1 = window.document.getElementById(out);
        out1.innerHTML = `${result}`
    }
</script>
```

Trecho de código em HTML:

```
    <h1>Fazendo a soma</h1>
<input type="number" name="txtn1" id="n1" />
<input type="number" name="txtn2" id="n2" />
<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="somar()" />
<p id="out">Resultado</p>
```

Comment: Vc tem que pegar os valores dentro da função e faltou colocar `.value`, além das aspas como citado na resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns erros no seu código, vamos por partes.

1º) Para pegar um elemento HTML com o método `document.getElementById()`, você deve passar para ele uma string, o que não acontece. Você está passando aí uma variável, só que nessa variável não tem o nome do elemento HTML que deseja pegar.

2º) O mesmo acontece dentro da função `somar()`, onde, em vez de uma string, você passa uma variável para o método `document.getElementById()`. Portanto, quando você passa um argumento para um método sem o uso de aspas, o interpretador vai entender que aquele argumento é uma variável, constante, função, etc. Quando ele não encontra, dá um erro, como acontece no seu código.

3º) Com o método `document.getElementById()`, você está tentando pegar o elemento, não o valor que está dentro dele. Para pegar o valor de um  `input`, você deve fazer `document.getElementById('nomeDoElemento').value`.

Dito isso, teoricamente seu código deve funcionar assim:

```js
    n1 = window.document.getElementById('n1').value;
    n2 = window.document.getElementById('n2').value;
    
    function somar() {
        var n11 = Number.parseFloat(n1);
        var n22 = Number.parseFloat(n2);
        var result = n11 + n22;
        var out1 = window.document.getElementById('out');
        out1.innerHTML = `${result}`
    }
```

```html
<h1>Fazendo a soma</h1>
<input type="number" name="txtn1" id="n1" />
<input type="number" name="txtn2" id="n2" />
<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="somar()" />
<p id="out">Resultado</p>
```

No entanto, ele AINDA NÃO FUNCIONA COMO O ESPERADO. A gente recebe um `NaN` (not a number) quando clicamos no botão somar, isso porque, quando clicamos, dentro da função `somar()`, `n1` e `n2` são `null`. O motivo pelo qual elas são `null`, é que estão declaradas no topo do código, e como o código é interpretado de cima para baixo, ao passar por essa parte do código, o interpretador tenta atribuir o valor do input a eles, MAS O INPUT AINDA NÃO FOI REDENRIZADO NESSA PARTE, ou seja, ainda não existe.

Para contornar isso, podemos, por exemplo, declarar as variáveis `n1` e `n2` somente dentro da função `somar()`, assim, quando clicarmos no botão somar, teremos a certeza de que eles não receberão null, visto que os inputs (elementos HTML) já terão sido renderizados.

Assim, o código correto é o seguinte:

```js
    function somar() {
        var n1 = window.document.getElementById('n1').value;
        var n2 = window.document.getElementById('n2').value;
        var n11 = Number.parseFloat(n1);
        var n22 = Number.parseFloat(n2);
        var result = n11 + n22;
        var out1 = window.document.getElementById('out');
        out1.innerHTML = `${result}`
    }
```

```html
<h1>Fazendo a soma</h1>
<input type="number" name="txtn1" id="n1" />
<input type="number" name="txtn2" id="n2" />
<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="somar()" />
<p id="out">Resultado</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema. E obrigado por dispor do seu tempo para explicar detalhadamente, me ajudou a entender melhor.

Answer (score 1):

O nome do ID tem que ser passado como string.

Ao invés de (n1) e (n2), tem que ser ('n1')  e ('n2') ou  ("n1")  e ("n2"), aspas simples ou duplas para indicar que é string.

Outro ponto é que precisa informar o que deseja do elemento, o que no caso, você deseja o valor do mesmo, logo tem que adicionar o ".value" ao final.

Depois é que tudo se repete a cada vez que clicar no botão, então tudo faz parte da função somar, ou seja, move-se tudo para dentro da função.

Exemplo corrigido e funcionando no snippet abaixo:

```js
function somar() {

    var n1 = window.document.getElementById('ns1').value; // <<-- Aqui é 'n1' com aspas simples ou duplas
    
    var n2 = window.document.getElementById('n2').value; // <<-- Aqui é 'n2' com aspas simples ou duplas
 
    var n11 = Number.parseFloat(n1);
    var n22 = Number.parseFloat(n2);
    var result = n11 + n22;
    var out1 = window.document.getElementById('out');
            out1.innerHTML = `${result}`
}
```

```html
<h1>Fazendo a soma</h1>

<input type="number" name="txtn1" id="ns1" />

<input type="number" name="txtn2" id="n2" />

<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="somar()" />

<p>Resultado: <span id="out"></span></p>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Fiz as alterações recomendadas mas ainda sem funcionar.

Comment: Ajustei a resposta lá com os ajustes, agora está 100%.

Comment: Obrigado. Sua resposta e a do colega abaixo me ajudou a solucionar a dúvida.